# Can classical orders coexist with quantum orders?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

For example, the ground state of the antiferromagnetic(AFM) Heisenberg model $H=J\sum_{<ij>}\mathbf{S}_i \cdot \mathbf{S}_j(J>0)$ on a 2D square lattice is a Neel state, which is a classical order described by conventional order parameters $\left \langle \mathbf{S}_i \right \rangle$.

On the other hand, if we use the Schwinger-fermion mean-field theory to study $H$, we  will get a mean-field Hamiltonian $H_{MF}=\sum (f_i^\dagger \chi_{ij} f_j+f_i^\dagger \eta_{ij} f_j^\dagger+H.c.)$ which is studied in Wen's [papers of PSG](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v65/i16/e165113), and now we can study the PSG of the mean-field ansatz $(\chi_{ij},\eta_{ij})$ and associated quantum order.

So according to the above example, can we say that the AFM SDW phase(classical order) *possesses* the quantum order(PSG)? Thank you very much.

Comment: In my books the classical orders emerge from the quantum mechanical orders. In other words the basic level is quantum mechanical and the classical is a limiting case macroscopically. Coexist does not describe the relationship  accurately.

Comment: @  anna v, can you give me a link to your books? Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, it is just an english expession "in my books". I can give you a link to Motl's blog where he shows how from photons one gets the classical electromagnetic field: http://motls.blogspot.gr/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html

Comment: I just found a [nice work](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6948) by Prof.Daghofer, which shows the **coexistence**  of both topological order and classical order.